# Packet Sniffing iphone traffic involving SIP pckets

Tags: iphone, sip, packet-sniffers

Is there a way to sniff the incoming and outgoing packets of iphone , which contains SIP pckets as well , using windows or Mac ??
It will be better if someone provide me a link to such tutorial ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

1) Instal a network protocol analyzer (on your MAC\Win) like: [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html) (free) or [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) (trial)

2) activate "Internat sharing" on you MAC

3) Connect your wireless devices

4) Run your network analyzer

You have Documentation \ Help page on each site